# Need last nth digit from a particular variable

Tags: shell, unix

```
12131X> lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid

200407-12:37:05 12131X 18.0m MSRBS_NODE_MODEL_18.Q4_369.27924.51_aace stopfile=/tmp/11836
=================================================================================================================
MO                                                      Attribute         Value
=================================================================================================================
Iub=12131X                                  rbsId             1170028601
=================================================================================================================
Total: 1 MOs

$rbsid = 1170028601
```

Now i want to store `$rbsid1 = 0028601`  (last 7 digits)

`echo $rbsid1`  should be `0028601`

it is unix and how to store

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS as per forum rules.

Comment: lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid

it fetched from Node and found some digit like 1170028601 and I want to store only last 7 digit ex: 0028601 How to fetch the data,
i am using UNIX

Answer (score 0):

Reverse a variable and cut off undesired parts:

```
$echo $rbsid 
1170028601
$rbsid1=$(echo $rbsid  |  rev |  cut -c1-7 | rev)
$echo $rbsid1 
0028601
$
```

Comment: $rbsid1 = $(echo $rbsid  |  rev |  cut -c1-7 | rev)
while trying to fetch it is showing output like this:

$rbsid1 = $(echo 1170028601 | rev | cut -c1-7 | rev)

any other solution

Comment: Please share output of `echo $rbsid`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: echo $rbsid output is :  1170028601
but while trying to cut or tail it is not working,
but while trying to $rbsid = $rbsid - 1  out put is 1170028600, 
so in this case it is integer only and need to fetch last 7th digit only in integer.

Comment: Hi,
else how to remove first 3 digits of a variable in unix 
ex: $var= 13782345
how to store 82345 from $var in unix shell script.